# What is the best practice to maximize reuse of code when targeting android and ios

Tags: android, ios, architecture

**What is the best practice to maximize reuse of code when targeting android and ios**

For example if I wish to write an equivalent application on both Android and IOS devices what are some ways to create code which will give the most re-usability on both target platforms??

Comment: Android and iOS use completely different languages. With that in mind, what do you mean?

Comment: Is there no way to build a common core library to use in both platforms?

Comment: You would have to convert all the code over. This will be easier after the version in one language is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good example of such code sharing application: **Gmail**

They write ui independed code for `Java` and then use `J2ObjC` translator to convert it into `Objective-C`. Here is the links:

[Some gmail information](https://gmail.googleblog.com/2014/11/going-under-hood-of-inbox.html)

[Open source Java to Object-C translator](http://j2objc.org/)